# Bad Synonym for APT

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I think that the `apt` tag shouldn't have been set to a synonym of `apt-get` but it should have been the other way around. `apt` is the technology, `apt-get` is one of many ways to use apt.

Probably we should have had something like `apt-get` `apt-cache` `aptitude` and `synaptic` aliased to `apt` or no synonym at all.

Comment: I agree, I think I may have even proposed or upvoted that synonym.  I remember thinking that it probably should have been the other way around.

Comment: Reversed the apt /apt-get synonym, but I'll leave the other apt synonym variations to you pros in the area.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed.  Forgive my ignorance (n00bness) to Meta, but is is possible in current functionality to allow the user to select the tag but replace it with the "recommended"/"approved" tag?

In this instance, any tag entry of any or all of:
apt
apt-get
apt-cache
etc

would be replaced with a tag of "synaptic" or "aptitude"?

If I'm not clear, or this is how the synonyms already work, please let me know.

Comment: I think you're asking about the [tag synonym feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms). Most of the SE engine functionality discussion takes place on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  These features eventually trickle-down to the other SE sites.

Comment: Not sure why you got -1. Maybe someone thinks your answer should have been a comment?

Comment: @jscott Thank you for the insight and input.  I'll take a look at those references.  I have been in both metas but lost track of which one I was in.